# React functional component is called on every parent state change

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in React and I found thing that makes me confused.

Almost every tutorial suggests using functional (stateless) components.
But recently I discovered that if functional component is a child component, it is rendered every time when parent component state or props changed even if I don't pass any props to it.
It doesn't happen with class-based component. 
What is the reason for this situation?

Should I use only class-based components in order to get the highest performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are your options out of the box:

1. Use a pure function like you did:

   - [+] Easy to write and to understand
   - [-] Rerenders each time the parent component rerenders (might not be an issue if you don't pass it any props though)
2. Use a class component and implement shouldComponentUpdate

   - [+] you have full control over the rerendering conditions.
   - [-] Takes a lot more code to write
3. Use a [PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent)

   - [+] uses a shallow shouldComponentUpdate automagically so less code to write
   - [-] can have undesirable side effects (false negative for complex objects and non pure child components not rendering properly)

In your particular case, since you are not passing any props to your child component, using a pure function is perfectly acceptable. Because that means its just pure static HTML and would rerender each time anyways even if it was part of the parent.

Lastly, for more advanced uses, have a look at https://github.com/acdlite/recompose

Comment: Thanks for your answer but still I don't know why functional component rerenders in contrast to class component

Comment: Is there a problem with these re-renders that you see?   the Virtual Dom and the resolution model for it make renders that don't actually change anything very cheap CPU-wise.  Plus, I'm not sure I believe that class-based child components don't re-render.. they do, unless you tell them not to. 
 Maybe you mean connected components?
 https://www.codecademy.com/articles/react-virtual-dom

Comment: function components are just dumb functions. They are executed each time they are present in the code. Class components rerender the same way UNLESS you implement the shouldComponentUpdate method and explicitely tell them not to

Comment: You are right guys, my class based component was connected with store.